# Birthday problem: Let X be number of people needed for a match. Find the PMF of X.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> People are arriving at a party one at a time. While waiting for more people to arrive they entertain themselves by comparing their birthdays. Let X be the number of people needed to obtain a birthday match, i.e., before person X arrives there are no two people with the same birthday, but when person X arrives there is a match. Find the PMF of X. (Introduction to Probability, Blitzstein and Hwang, p.128)

The CDF is $P(X\leq k) = 1 - \frac{\binom{365}{k}k!}{365^k}$, so the PMF can be obtained by:

\begin{align}
\\
P(X=k) &= P(X\leq k) - P(X\leq k-1)\\\\
&= \left( 1 - \frac{\binom{365}{k}k!}{365^k} \right) - \left( 1 - \frac{\binom{365}{k-1}(k-1)!}{365^{k-1}} \right) \\\\
&= \frac{(k-1)}{365^k} \binom{365}{k-1}  (k-1)! \\\\
&=(k-1)*\left(1-P(X \leq k-1 \right)) \\\\
&= (k-1) * P(X > k-1)
\end{align}

Is this correct? How do you interpret the results? How to arrive at the PMF without using the CDF?

Answer (score 8):

There is an easier way, which lead to the correct answer.

You want $P(k)$, the probability that the first match occurs at person $k$.  For that to happen, 
the previous $k-1$ people must have no matches, and $X$ must match one of them.

The probability of $k-1$ people to have no matches is
$$
\frac{N}{N} \frac{N-1}{N} \frac{N-2}{N} \cdots \frac{N-k+2}{N} = \frac{N!}{(N-k+1)! N^{k-1}}
$$
with $N = 365$. 
Then the probability of a match on the k-th person is
$$ P(k) = \frac{N!}{(N-k+1)! N^{k-1}} \frac{k-1}{N} = (k-1) \frac{N!}{(N-k+1)! N^{k}}
$$

The expression you give is equivalent to $(k-1) \frac{N!}{(N-k+1)! N^{k}}$. But this derivation did not use the CDF.

Comment: This makes sense, but is there a way to immediately see that $P(X=k) = (k-1) P(X \geq k)$ is true?